# Will My Electronic-system survive? // No Proper Grounding on factory Floor

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, ground, short-circuit, surge-protection

I have built a simple system which reads the sensor data and displays it on LCD display.
Sensor type: **Strain gauge type**
SMPS: **[MEANWELL Net35-b](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/260/net-35-spec-1109582.pdf)**
PCB: Local made, single side
Case: Metallic
 I want to fit this system on a factory floor.Factory in-charge previously  faced 2 major issues with similar system

1)**NO PROPER GROUNDING** (Equipment Malfunction)

2)**POWER SURGE**(Up to 380-400 volts)

**My analysis:**:
1)a)From what I've read I think that no grounding issue is serious and can cause someone to get electrocuted.
  b)From what I have read, there is no problem to SMPS that can lead to system malfunction from faulty grounding so electronics is safe (humans not so much !).I have connected the metallic cover of SMPS to the metal case.

2)For problem number 2 I think that those guys need to buy a servo stabilizer.
In Datasheet of SMPS Maximum input ratings are **"85 ~ 264VAC"** . 380-400VAC is Way more than acceptable limits.

**Questions :**

1) Are there any more problems associated with no proper grounding? Is there a possibility of damage to the system ?

2)What will happen in the case of power surge? Will SMPS shut-down?

3)What should I do to avoid instrument malfunction like previous instruments?

I don't know much about electrical safety circuits.Any Suggestions and help are appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Warning: I'm not an electrician so take the following with a big pinch of salt.

Lack of ground is a severe danger. If a metal case is not grounded, and a live cable touches it, the case is then at live potential. Ground mitigates this in two ways: the above scenario will cause a large current to earth, blowing a fuse. Or better yet, with an RCD device, just a small current will trip it.

Many configurations of ground are used depending on country, supply, and installation. At some point, somewhere, AFAIK ground and neutral are connected. If properly installed, it **might** be acceptable to create your own ground by connecting to neutral. I know this will get a negative vote, unless I say that this is conceptual only and really, **really** needs to be determined by a qualified electrician. But in principle, it's how an otherwise non-existent ground could be established. Saying that, **it is a BAD idea to randomly go around connecting earth to neutral**. One reason among many is neutral may not actually be at true ground potential.

Power surges: this is a different issue. You can get power conditioners that you use between the supply and installation. But what you use depends entirely on the kinds of surges you're experiencing. Firstly your energy  provider should have a guarantee of minimum supply quality. Use that to determine what protection you need.

Finally, each piece of equipment you use should have adequate protection and failure handling on a per-item basis so none can cause, or be susceptible to line fluctuations. If some equipment is causing problems, it may need repair. Otherwise, some form of isolation will be needed but this could be complex and expensive, and it's most likely to be better all round to just get a better unit.

Your SMPS is not rated for the supply voltage. It will probably quickly die and very possibly become very dangerous. Also - connecting case grounds together could be as bad as disconnected - if there's a fault, as I describe at the top, the case could become live.